# Updating Javascript Variables With Ajax/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been having some issues with refreshing my game. At first, I tried echoing the entire script each time... But that wasn't pretty. Now I'm trying to simply update the variables with an Ajax request. My code for Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshMap();
});

function refreshMap(){
    $('#mapVars').load('<?php print"$game_link_play" ?>/ajax/getPrepareMap.php?id=<?php print"$game_id";?>', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshMap, 5000);
    });
}
</script>
```

getPrepareMap.php:

```
<?php
echo"
    <script>
        var nationColors = {
                'DE': '#990000',
                'GB': '#009999',
                'FR': '#009999',
            };

            var nationLeaders = {
                'DE': 'Adolf Hitler',
                'GB': 'Winston Churchill',
                'FR': 'Winston Churchill',
            };

            var nationPopulation = {
                'DE': '81,000,000',
                'GB': '54,000,000',
                'FR': '64,000,000',
            }

    </script>
";
?>
```

The script for loading the map:

```
<script>
$(function (){

    function chkLeader(val){
        if (typeof val ==="undefined"){
          x = "No Leader";
        }
        else {
          x = val;
        }
        return x;
    };

    markers = [
    {latLng: [52.50, 13.39], name: 'Berlin'},
    {latLng: [51.5, 0.13], name: 'London'},
    {latLng: [48.85, 2], name: 'Paris'}
  ],

  cityData = [
    100,
    100,
    100
  ]


  map = new jvm.WorldMap({

    container: $('#map'),
    map: 'europe_mill_en',
    backgroundColor: '#1C6BA0',
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    markers: markers,

    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#78B6A4',
        }
    },

    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        }
    },
    series: {
        regions: [{
            attribute: 'fill'
        }], 

        markers: [{
            attribute: 'r',
            scale: [5, 6],
            values: cityData
        }]
    },

    onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
        label.html(
            '<strong>' + 
                label.html() + 
            '</strong>' + '<br>' + 

            '<strong>' + 
                'Leader: ' + 
            '</strong>' + 

            chkLeader(nationLeaders[code]) + '<br>' +

            '<strong>' + 
                'Population: ' + 
            '</strong>' +

            nationPopulation[code]

            );
        }

  });

     map.series.regions[0].setValues(nationColors);
});
```

Edit: I can get the new variables into the page, BUT the map won't refresh?

New Code For Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  refreshMap();
});

function refreshMap(){
    $('#mapVars').load('<?php print"$game_link_play" ?>/ajax/getPrepareMap.php?id=<?php print"$game_id";?>', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshMap, 5000);
    });

    mapReload();
}
```

New Code for Map Load Script:

```
$(function mapReload(){
    function chkLeader(val){
        if (typeof val ==="undefined"){
          x = "No Leader";
        }
        else {
          x = val;
        }
        return x;
    };

    markers = [
    {latLng: [52.50, 13.39], name: 'Berlin'},
    {latLng: [51.5, 0.13], name: 'London'},
    {latLng: [48.85, 2], name: 'Paris'}
  ],

  cityData = [
    100,
    100,
    100
  ]


  map = new jvm.WorldMap({

    container: $('#map'),
    map: 'europe_mill_en',
    backgroundColor: '#1C6BA0',
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    markers: markers,

    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#78B6A4',
        }
    },

    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        }
    },
    series: {
        regions: [{
            attribute: 'fill'
        }], 

        markers: [{
            attribute: 'r',
            scale: [5, 6],
            values: cityData
        }]
    },

    onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
        label.html(
            '<strong>' + 
                label.html() + 
            '</strong>' + '<br>' + 

            '<strong>' + 
                'Leader: ' + 
            '</strong>' + 

            chkLeader(nationLeaders[code]) + '<br>' +

            '<strong>' + 
                'Population: ' + 
            '</strong>' +

            nationPopulation[code]

            );
        }

  });

     map.series.regions[0].setValues(nationColors);
});
```

But for some reason the page goes blank :(

Comment: What are you doing with the variables after the AJAX call returns?

Comment: Basically, I am loading a map. I want the AJAX call to get new variable values for the map and update them. I tried putting ALL of the Javascript into the AJAX request and it sort of worked. But the issue was that the DIVS that showed when hovering would still show if you took your mouse off after another AJAX update.

Comment: You're just updating the variables. You need to call the appropriate map method to make it update the map using the new variables.

Comment: Where would I put that call?

Comment: In the callback function. BTW, instead of calling `setTimeout` every time, use `setInterval` to create a function that runs every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar When I try, the page goes blank. I must not be doing it right.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Add your new code at the end of the question.

Comment: @Barmar I added the new code the the edit. I will check the console.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: mapReload is not defined

Comment: You need to define the `mapReload()` function outside `$()`, or put the definition of `refreshMap()` inside it, so they're in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

`mapReload` needs to be called in the callback:

```
$(function() {

    refreshMap();

    function mapReload() {
        ...
    }

    function refreshMap(){
        $('#mapVars').load('<?php print"$game_link_play" ?>/ajax/getPrepareMap.php?id=<?php print"$game_id";?>', function(){
            mapReload();
            setTimeout(refreshMap, 5000);
        });
    }

});
```

You defined `mapReload` using a named function expression, and in that syntax its name is only visible within the function body.

Comment: Should the mapReload(); Function be above the Ajax code? It's still coming up as undefined.

Comment: See my comment above. You need to get them in the same scope.

Comment: Alright, I put the AJAX below. It no longer is undefined BUT it still won't update to the new variables. :/

Comment: What do you see if you put `console.log(nationColors)` in the callback?

Comment: Oh wait, it's still showing as undefined. Could you show a code example on how I should define mapReload so it'll work in the callback?

Comment: I sort of got it to work but instead of updating the current map it is adding an entirely new map to the page right below each one

Comment: I guess that's because you call `new jvm.WorldMap` every time. I'm not familiar with this API, but I assume it provides operations to update an existing map instead of creating a new one, you need to check the documentation to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like I figured it all out. :)

Basically, I just had to put

```
map.series.regions[0].setValues(nationColors, nationLeaders, nationPopulation);
```

in the AJAX callback.

To update JVectorMap with Ajax, simply:

1. Make an AJAX request that loads JS variables into a script.
2. Have the AJAX request load the values using the above code.

This took six hours to figure out, but I am proud of myself.